# where to write a text file and how to set it up for an sd card

Tags: android, input, output, android-file

I know this is a popular question but I have looked at all of the other responses and none of them seem to work.  What I want to do is write some code to a text file. My first question: is there a way to view that text file without writing code to the console?  Second, I dont know where in my phone it goes and I want to see it to help trouble shoot, so if you know how to do that too, it would be great.  So now I will give you an overview of what is happening. When I start my program it checks to see if the file exists, if it doesn't it reads a file out of my assets folder and copies that info and sends it to a file into the sd card. If it exits it reads the info from the sd card. Next if I press a button and change numbers and print it to my sd card again then I close it using task managers then when I come back the original information is here. I don't feel like it is being able to find  my sd card location. So far I have used.

```
File outfilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String FileName = "ExSettings.txt" ;
File outfile = new File(outfilepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/TimeLeft/"+FileName);

File outfilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String FileName = "ExSettings.txt" ;
File outfile = new File(outfilepath, FileName);
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Many of them seem to work, since many others have used the code successfully, therefore, you cannot have looked at all the other responses.  In addition, your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to determine the path to the SDCard?  What problem, exactly, are you having?

Comment: If you're closing the program with a task manager, you may be killing the stream before it is flushed. A stream may not flush until it is explicitly told to do so in the code or it is properly closed in the code. Don't use task managers to stop apps. Call `stream.flush()` to force it to flush at the button press if you desire.

Comment: So if I needed to flush where would I call it and do I just need to call it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function that I wrote which will take in a list array and write to a file line by line.

It will use the path in fileName to make a new folder called `myfolder` in the root of the SDCard, an inside will be your file of `newtextfile.txt`.

```
List<String> File_Contents = new ArrayList<String>();

File_Contents.add("This is line one");
File_Contents.add("This is line two");

File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myfolder/newtextfile.txt");
f.mkDirs();

try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    for (int x = 0; x < File_Contents.size(); x++) {
        out.write(File_Contents.get(x));
        out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    out.close();
    return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok thx an actual example for once Haha... I will try that as soon as possible... Oh and how do I look at the file in my phone... Do I need to download something?

Comment: You phone may have a file manager by default, and if not there are tons of file managers on the Play store. Astro makes a very nice one.